# asp.net Run code when session is available but page has not been loaded?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, lifecycle

Is there any way to run code when session is available but page has not been loaded?

The closest thing i have found is Global.asax AcquireRequestState.

But it seems to run right after the constructor for the page.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm checking for a query parameter and settings a session variable if its found. this has to be done before a certain class is instantiated as this reads the session, the problem is that the class is instantiated in the constructor of many pages...

Comment: Can't you do it as part of that Class's constructor?

Comment: I only want this check to be executed once, the class is instanced in most of the pages and most of the usercontrols.